# How to delay application shutdown while running @Async tasks?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an async task executor.
How can I tell `Spring` to wait on application shutdown until all tasks are finished?

```
@Bean
public ThreadPoolExecutor singleExecutor() {
    return new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
            new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10),
            new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy());
}


@Service
class MyService {
    @Async("singleExecutor")
    public void runAsync() {
     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solution

The [`org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` class](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.15/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html) (implements the [`org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor` interface](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.15/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/TaskExecutor.html)) supports the requested functionality by the the following methods:

- [`setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.15/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ExecutorConfigurationSupport.html#setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown-boolean-).
- [`setAwaitTerminationSeconds()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.15/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ExecutorConfigurationSupport.html#setAwaitTerminationSeconds-int-).

Therefore, please, consider migrating the bean:

- From: `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor`.
- To: `org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor`.

### «Migrated bean» example

```
@Bean
public TaskExecutor singleExecutor() {
    final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(1);
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(1);
    taskExecutor.setKeepAliveSeconds(0);
    taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(10);
    taskExecutor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy());
    taskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    taskExecutor.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(300);
    return taskExecutor;
}
```

### `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` class: Queue type

Please, see the Javadoc for the [ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.createQueue() method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.15/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html#createQueue-int-) on the default queue factory method behaviour:

> protected [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html?is-external=true)<[Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html?is-external=true)> createQueue(int queueCapacity)
>
> Create the BlockingQueue to use for the ThreadPoolExecutor.
>
> A LinkedBlockingQueue instance will be created for a positive capacity value; a SynchronousQueue else.

It is possible to override the behaviour by using a class derived from the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` class with the overridden factory method.

For example:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;

public final class CustomThreadPoolTaskExecutor extends ThreadPoolTaskExecutor {
    @Override
    protected BlockingQueue<Runnable> createQueue(final int queueCapacity) {
        return new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(queueCapacity);
    }
}
```

Comment: So and is this (which creates a `LinkedBlockingQueue`) equivalent to a `ArrayBlockingQueue`? Because using `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`, I have no control over the type of queue, or do I?

Comment: Thanks, that's a great solution! Anyways I'd be interested if it makes any significant difference using an `ArrayBlockingQueue` explicit here, instead of relying on the spring default `LinkedBlockingQueue`?

Comment: @membersound, that is another question. Please, consider asking it as a separate question (not a comment).